# dbt Snapshot - if not execute

Tags: dbt

I have a dbt Snapshot that calls a Macro to get a list of column names back from a database.
It works fine when using

```
dbt run
```

when using the snapshot command it fails because it doesn't run in execute mode.

```
dbt snapshot
```

I am currently using if not execute in the Macro which helps for compiling the project.

```
{%- if not execute -%}
```

Is there anyway to get around this so I could use the Snapshot functionality without doing a run operation on all models etc?

Thanks

edit :

Macro works fine in models when running dbt run.
When placed in snapshots it runs not in execute mode so the "Test" values are returned instead of values from a query.

```
{% macro GetColumnNames(DatabaseName, SchemaName, TableName) %}

    {%- if not execute -%}
        {{ return(["Test1","Test2"]) }}
    {% endif %}

    {%- set QueryRetrieveColumnNames -%}

        SELECT
              ...
            , COLUMN_NAME ...
        FROM ...

    {%- endset -%}

    {% set Results = run_query(QueryRetrieveColumnNames) %}}

    {%- set ColumnNames = Results.columns[3].values() -%}}
    {{ return(ColumnNames) }}

{% endmacro %}
```

In the snapshot I'm doing other things, but even just the columns on their own won't work

```
{% snapshot TestSnapshot %}

    {% set Relation = source(...) -%}
    {% set ColumnNames = GetColumnNames(Relation.database, Relation.schema, Relation.identifier) -%}

SELECT
'a' AS a
{%- for ColumnName in ColumnNames %}
    , "{{ ColumnName.column }}"
{%- endfor %}

FROM {{ source(...) }}

{% endsnapshot %}
```

I've switched from the Macro to use get_columns_in_relation

```
{% set ColumnNames = adapter.get_columns_in_relation(Relation) -%}
```

This fails at parsing, yet runs fine in models.
Parsing Error in snapshot ...
at path ['check_cols']: Undefined is not valid under any of the given schemas

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the context of this question (dbtCloud, CLI etc.) so this is a ballpark solution.

According to the [docs on the snapshot](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/snapshot) command for the CLI, you should be able to use something like:

`dbt snapshot --select column_snapshot`

if that's the only thing you want to "snapshot"

Additionally, if this is in dbtCloud, you could create a model & job with something like the following (I use this for testing `pre-hook` & `post-hook` functionality)

`one-model.sql`

```
select 1
```

(any model with valid sql works)

Then for that cloud job:

1. `dbt seed --full-refresh`
2. `dbt run --models one-model --full-refresh`
3. `dbt snapshot --select column_snapshot`

Comment: Sorry - it's CLI.
I've tried dbt snapshot --select snapshotname
But it errors due to the Macro I use to bring back column names not running in execute mode to list the column names so it instead brings back "testcolumn" which isn't an actual field.

Comment: Can you include that macro in the question?

Comment: I've put some details about the macro in the main post.